# Filtering of Errors displayed in Error Window of VS2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have one .NET UI project and another managed C++ projects.

Unless and until I build C++ projects; .NET UI project keep showing the build errors all the time. This simply clutters the Error Window. Isn't there any option which will allow to manipulate what could be shown in Error Window?

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. "Managed C++" *is* a language targeting the .NET Framework. What do you mean by ".NET UI project"? And why don't you just set the dependencies correctly so that the build order is correct and the errors go away? Hiding errors is almost always the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably there is no dependencies set up for the projects in your solution, or dependencies are set up incorrectly.

You probably should make UI project dependent from your other projects. This way, the UI project will be built after other projects.

[How to: Create and Remove Project Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)